# Setting Start / End Time in Primeng Schedule

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, primeng

I would like to adopt the Primeng Schedule component https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule and I am looking for an example of a 'rich' Event Details Editor Dialog. The Primeng 'Event Details' popup sample only displays the date 'yyyy-MM-dd' for an event and I would need to be able to set / edit the event start and end time as well.

In the spirit of 'DRY' I believe this must have been done by others before me!
Can anybody point me to an example where I can see a working model?

I see that there is an older sample based on the underlying fullcalender jquery component that could be upgraded for angular here:
https://www.alinous.org/web-developer/design-pattern/fullcalendar/ . Failing all else I guess I could start with that.

Comment: Fixed the link. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule

Comment: Ok - primefaces tag removed.

Comment: Thanks, removed comments (this one too)

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."_

Comment: Thanks ADyson .I was trying to "describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: @MarkD. ok well sorry if you thought I'd misinterpreted your intention, but you clearly asked for a link to an existing example, which is definitely considered off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I can now answer my own question.

The embedded p-calendar component in the p-dialog HTML sample code can be updated to accommodate this by adding the showTime attribute and setting its value to "true".

The source for the sample HTML https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/showcase/components/schedule/scheduledemo.html can be modified to show a Time Picker:

To get started change this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-row">
    <div class="ui-grid-col-4"><label for="start">Start</label></div>
    <div class="ui-grid-col-8"><p-calendar [(ngModel)]="event.start" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" dataType="string"></p-calendar></div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-row">
    <div class="ui-grid-col-4"><label for="start">Start</label></div>
    <div class="ui-grid-col-8"><p-calendar [(ngModel)]="event.start" dateFormat="yy-mm-dd" showTime="true" dataType="string"></p-calendar></div>
</div>
```